# If an SVG shape has no "fill" style, how is it supposed to be rendered?

Tags: svg

The following SVG image contains a rectangle without a `style` attribute:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="50" height="50">
  <rect width="30" height="30" x="10" y="10" />
</svg>
```

Similarly, the rectangle in this image does have a `style` attribute, but without a `fill` property:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="50" height="50">
  <rect width="30" height="30" x="10" y="10" style="stroke:red" />
</svg>
```

In both cases, the rectangle is rendered as if it had a `fill:black` property (by Firefox, Chrome, and Inkscape).

Is this somehow mandated by the standard or is it an arbitrary choice made by the renderer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SVG specification [defines such things](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/painting.html#FillProperties)

> ‘fill’
>      Value:      (See Specifying paint)
>      Initial:   black

Everything about rendering should be defined in the SVG standard so that browsers are interoperable.